# Unpacking Bytes: Difference in Python 2 vs 3

Tags: python-3.x, arduino, pyserial, unpack

I'm trying to unpack data sent over from my Arduino with Pyserial. The code works on Python 2.7 however, the same code fails on Python 3.4, and I have no idea why. This is the code.

```
resp=ser.read()
datalength=struct.unpack('<b',resp)[0]
data=ser.read(datalength)
temp = struct.unpack('<'+'h'*int(datalength/2),data)
ser.flushInput()
ser.flushOutput()
print(temp)
```

This is the resulting error in Python 3.4:

```
temp=struct.unpack('<'+'h'*int(datalength/2),data)
struct.error: unpack requires a bytes object of length 36
```

I printed out `resp`, `datalength` and `data` to see what's going on.

```
Resp:  b'$'
Datalength:  36
Data:  b'M>\x06l\xf6\xff\x00\x00\x14\x00w'
```

To get the full response, I did `ser.readline()` and it returned:

```
b'$M>\x06l\xab\xff\x13\x00O\x00b'
```

Could someone explain the difference on the `.unpacking` process in Py2 vs Py3 and why it works on Py2 and not 3?

I'm trying to parse data from my Multiwii if that helps at all, all Multwii parses are in Py2 and not 3....

Comment: Note that `.read(size)` tries to read **up to** `size` bytes. Perhaps you simply need to iterate until you actually have received that many bytes?

Comment: What do you mean? Could I do `.read(size+1)` instead?

Comment: `while len(data) < datalength: data += ser.read(datalength - len(data))`, perhaps with a timeout?

Comment: I implemented what you said, and it continuously loops, never ending, so it never constructs `temp`, even with `data=b''` before the `while` loop.

Comment: As I said: *perhaps with a timeout*. There are two possibilities here: the length is wrong, or not all bytes are received. Is the message really 36 bytes long? Did things get out of sync on previous reads?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a result of the Python version. It's most likely because `read()` isn't waiting long enough for all the data (36 bytes, apparently) to arrive. Try increasing the timeout argument for your serial object and see if anything changes, like this:

```
ser = serial.Serial(port, baud, timeout=2)
```

Unit is seconds.